# DynamoDB query table for two indexed fields

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In my dynamoDB table I have two fields which I intend to query for a specific value. One will returns several results, the second will return one result (aka one row).

I already have a range key field which is the date that the raw inserted.

What are my options if I want to have two fields to query by a single field?

From my understanding, there is an option to create a secondary index, but I must query it alongside with the hash key, which is not what I need. Is there any option to achieve that in a single table instead of creating a second table for that query?

Example Folders table:

```
 user_id (hash key)    
 date_created (range key)    
 folder_id
```

**First query**: Select all folders Id's for a specific user order by date descending

**Second query**: Select single raw for a specific folder_id

If I use secondary index on the folder_id, I will have to query it alongside the user_id (hash key), which is as you can see, not what I want to achieve.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said yourself, you can't use LSI in this scenario.

You will have to create another table where folder_id is the hash key and the rest of the data as attributes.

Answer (score 6):

You need a Global Secondary Index.

```
folder_id (hash key)
date_created (range) - optional
```

Then you can also query by the folder_id

Answer (score 1):

You can also query for one primary key that will return the least amount of results than filter out the rest in code.